# php file in local host is not getting the json array sent from an android app

Tags: php, android, json

I have an app that produces this json array: [{"Name":"Apple","Quantity":"8"},
{"Name":"Beef","Quantity":"9"},{"Name":"Vegitable","Quantity":"5"}]

I am using a json parser class to send this array to a php file in my local host. The app successfully post the data to the php file but in return gets this garbage value. The logcat view is

```
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): [ 06-30 15:08:32.381  1157: 1172 D/    <br />
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspa    <br />
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: json in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\postingdata.php on line <i>33</i></th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0090</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>146968</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\postingdata.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\postingdata.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): </table></font>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <br />
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\postingdata.php on line <i>35</i></th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0090</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>146968</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\postingdata.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\postingdata.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-30 15:08:32.381: W/System.err(1157): </table></font>
```

I can not figure out where the problem lies and how to get the json array generated from the app be received by the php file in my local host. So please some one help me to solve this.

This is my JsonParse class:

```
 public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getandpostJSONFromUrl(String url, String method,JSONArray name) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            if (method.equals("POST") ) {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                Log.d("Json Array content",""+name);
                StringEntity se=new StringEntity(name.toString());
                Log.e("Json Array content",""+se);
                se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpPost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
//              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                int response = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
//              is = httpEntity.getContent();
//              Log.e("posting Status", "Post status: " + response);
                 String text = null;
                 if(response==200){

                        HttpEntity entity=httpResponse.getEntity();
                        text=EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);
                            //text=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(name);
                            text=jsonArray.getString(0);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        String tag=text;
                        Log.d(tag, text);
                    }


            }
            if (method.equals("GET") ) {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (method == "POST") {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer error", "Buffer error" + e);
            }

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

This is the php file i am using to get the json array:

```
 <?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'a1422982_sshop');
                    define('DB_USER', 'root');
                    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
                    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


                    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

                    if(!$link){
                    die('could not connect: '.msql_error());
                    }

                    $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

                    if(!$db_selected){
                    die('Can not  use '.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
                    }              



                    $jarray = $_POST['json'];
                    $parsed = json_decode($jarray , true);
                    foreach ($parsed as $obj) {
                         $ProductName = $obj['Name'];   
                         $ProductQuantity= $obj['Quantity'];

                         echo   $ProductName." ".$ProductQuantity;
                     }




    ?>
```

Comment: You are getting a PHP error, that's the 'garbage': Notice: Undefined index: json in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\postingdata.php on line 33.

Comment: That's while header json is only set after the execute() call. That should be done before i would think.

Comment: line 33 is this line "$jarray = $_POST['json'];" @Nico. I don't know why this error is for.